# How do I resolve a `NameError` in python?

Tags: python

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

def data_limiter(num, total_captions, all_img_name_vector):
    train_captions, img_name_vector = shuffle(total_captions, all_img_name_vector, random_state=1)
    train_captions = train_captions[:num]
    img_name_vector = img_name_vector[:num]
    return train_captions, img_name_vector

train_captions,img_name_vector = data_limiter(40000, total_captions, all_img_name_vector)
```

I tried running the code but it shows error saying:

```
NameError: name 'total_captions' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to define total_captions via

```
total_captions= ...
```

before you can use it.

Please put your code example a code block next time. And the shuffle method is also defined outside of your snippet.

I hope I could help, cheers
Leo